# Como dividir una fecha en phpmyAdmin con sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

34 Con una consulta obtén el nombre, año de nacimiento y mes de nacimiento
de cada uno de los alumnos.

```
SELECT nombre, fecha_nacimiento FROM alumnos;
```

No sé como resolver este ejercicio ya que la fecha de nacimiento guarda la fecha completa con el año-mes-dia, Aquí está la tabla que uso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es algo sencillo, puedes usar las funciones YEAR(),MONTH(),DAY()

```
SELECT expendiente,nombre,localidad,YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) as AÑO,MONTH(fecha_nacimiento) as MES,DAY(fecha_nacimiento) as DIA, direccion,curso,nivel,ISNULL(faltas,0) FROM alumnos;
```

Así lo haría yo, con eso separas el año, mes y día cada uno en cada columna

(De extra agregue el ISNULL a faltas para que no manejes nulls pero es algo extra)

Comment: muchas gracias de nuevo Mauricio, donde has encontrado esa función?

Comment: Son cosas que se aprenden con el tiempo en mi caso, pero siempre buscando la documentacion de SQL puedes encontrar bastantes funciones que facilitan las consultas